# display image from database in the html form using php

Tags: php

```
<?php
     $itemId=(\filter_input(\INPUT_POST,'itemId'));
     $title=(\filter_input(\INPUT_POST,'title'));
     $subtitle=(\filter_input(\INPUT_POST,'subtitle'));
     $availability=(\filter_input(\INPUT_POST,'availability'));
     $price=(\filter_input(\INPUT_POST,'price'));
     $custopt=(\filter_input(\INPUT_POST,'custopt'));
     $r1=(\filter_input(\INPUT_POST,'r1'));
     $r2=(\filter_input(\INPUT_POST,'r2'));
     $c1=(\filter_input(\INPUT_POST,'c1'));
     $c2=(\filter_input(\INPUT_POST,'c2'));
     $filename=$_FILES["photo"]["name"];
     $sql="select * from starterveg where itemId='$itemId'";
     $result=  \mysqli_query($dbhandle,$sql);
     /* @var $header type */
     $row=  \mysqli_fetch_array($result);
     if($row['itemId']===$itemId || $row['title']===$title)  
      {
        $itemId=$row['itemId'];
        $title=$row['title'];
        $subtitle=$row['subtitle'];
        $descript=$row['descript'];  
        $availability=$row['availability'];
        $price=$row['price'];
        $r1=$row['r1'];
        $r2=$row['r2'];
        $c1=$row['c1'];
        $c2=$row['c2'];
         $filename=$row['filename'];
       } 
 ?>
```

html file:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Add</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="pdtcatdesign.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Product Catalog</h1>
    <script src="addimage.js"></script>
    <form id="addform" method="post" action="adddbconn.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id='itemId' name="itemId" type='text' value="<?php echo $itemId ?>"/>
        <input id='title' name="title" type='text' value="<?php echo $title ?>"/>
        <input id='subtitle' name="subtitle" type='text' value="<?php echo $subtitle?>"/>
        <textarea id="descript" name="descript" cols="68" rows="3"><?=$descript?></textarea>
     <input type="radio" id="ra1" name="availability" value="Yes" <?php if($row['availability']==='Yes') : ?>  checked="checked" <?php endif; ?>/>
        <input type="radio" id="ra2" name="availability" value="No" <?php if($row['availability']==='No') : ?>  checked="checked" <?php endif; ?> />

        <input id="price" name="price" type="text" value="<?php echo $price?>;"/>            
        <input id="r1" name="r1" type="text" value="<?php echo $r1?>"/>
        <input id="r2" name="r2" type="text" value="<?php echo $r2?>"/>
        <input type="text" name="c1" id="c1" value="<?php echo $c1?>"/>
        <input type="text" name="c2" id="c2" value="<?php echo $c2?>"/>
    <input type="file" id="uploadImage" name="photo" onchange="PreviewImage();"/>
        <img id="uploadPreview"  style="width:100px;height:100px;"  alt=image src="#"/>

        </div>
    <canvas id="rect" width="300" height="75"></canvas>
        <div>

        <input type="submit" id="sub" value="Save" name="save"/>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

> Blockquote

i have a php page called **update.php**,it has a text box where the item id is entered.When i click the submit button,it opens **display.php** where all the details are     retrieved from mysql database and displayed in html form, except the image.How to retrieve image from database and display in the html form through php code?help me out to retrieve image from database to html form..

Comment: what have you tried so far friend? and while retrieving the data from sql you can also get image data by specifying image coulumn and get the image data

Comment: can you give some example code to retrieve image from database to html?

Comment: Store in database the name of the file (with path included) and the use a sentence to print the HTML code necessary to display that image.

Comment: Questions referring to code you've written should include the [relevant parts of the code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please read this [advice on how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Be sure to follow the link at the bottom to Jon Skeet's blog post [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx). Pay special attention to the "Golden Rule", though I highly advise you to read the entire article.

Answer (score 0):

You are not very clear about what you want. Assuming you are trying to display an image based on the results from your database:

**Option 1:** `base64_encode` your image and retreive it from the database.

```
// Store the image
    $image = imagecreatefromstring("file/path");
    ob_start();
    imagepng($image);
    $content =  ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    $result = base64_encode($content);
    imagedestroy($image);

// Display the image
    echo '<img src="data:image/gif;base64,' . $data . '" />';
```

**Option 2:** Save the image file on your webserver and store the image path in the database.

```
echo '<img src="' . $dbresult . '">
```

I would personally use `option 2`.

Answer (score 0):

Best approach is to store only the path in the database, since that saves a lot of CPU resources. Use a code like this to display the image:

```
print '<img src="http://mybeautifulsite.byethost22.com/' . $articles->image_1 . '" width="100%" alt="' . $articles->image_1 . '"/>';
```

Just adapt it to your own situation. It is very easy.